# Datatables: How to add custom server-side styling?

Tags: javascript, php, css, datatable

I'm using datatables on a simple HTML table. This table however is build server-side by my PHP script.

So I just build a 'table' element with 'thead' and 'tbody' in it, and apply datatables to the table element after page load.

Previously (before using datables), I could customize the styling of the table by setting a specific class for rows, cells, etc..

However it seems that when specifying a custom class like e.g.:

```
<tr class='MyCustomClass'>
```

is overwritten when datatables are applied to it.

Is there a setting in datatables that will include my custom classes? Reading the documentation there are a lot of styling options in datatables, but as far as I can find these are all javascript functions which have to executed client-side, so if those are my only option for styling datatables, It would be quite difficult to implement server-side styling depending on the content of a given row, cell, etc...

**Edit**

Example:

- OK: Table (without datatables loader) with 2nd row marked in red: http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1164/
- Not OK: Same table with datatables loaded, no red border around 2nd row to be seen: http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1163/

Note that in both examples the html source table has "style='border-color: red; border-style: solid" in the 2nd 'tr' element, however when loading datatables over this table, the red border is not visible

Answer (score 0):

So are you loading the table HTML dynamically?  If you are 'echoing' the results, you should place the inline css properties along with the echo statement.

```
echo "<tr style='border:1px solid red>'" . $row['myRow'] . "</tr>";
```

Comment: sorry but I don't see why this matters. In the jsfiddle example I wrote static html, and still it doesn't work, AFAIK it doesn't really matter whats outputting the html code, if it doesn't work with static code in the first place

Answer (score 0):

In your example that says "Not OK", it looks like the styling was maintained. It wasn't on the second row, but **it was around** the `Trident   Internet Explorer | 5.0 | Win 95+   | 5 | C` row if you go to the 5th "page".

DataTables sorted the results by the 'Rendering Engine' column which pushes Trident to the 5th page.

It may not be easy to override the styles that conflict with DataTables, but it looks like classes and inline styling can be applied. See the [updated example here](http://jsfiddle.net/HEDvf/1704/) where I override the font style and the background color.

You probably found some way to accommodate your needs by now, but DataTables aren't necessarily opposed to letting you add your own style.

Answer (score 0):

I already had to do this, this is an example, if based him, I said that when the column 3 equals column 4 will be added a class named 'red' in the `<tr>`

Example:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {                
    if ( aData[3] != aData[4]){
        jQuery(nRow).addClass('red');
    }               
},
```

http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/2025/fnrowcallback-and-fnupdate